# angularjs scope variable is not updating in routeChangeSuccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angularjs-scope, javascript-databinding

AngularJs starting point app.js

```
.config(function ($routeProvider,$interpolateProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/page/:pageid', {
    templateUrl: function (params) {
                        return 'views/' + params.pageid + 'detail.html'; 
                                                },
    controller: 'PageCtrl'
  }).
 .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

PageCtrl Js file

```
 .controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$timeout,$location,$rootScope,$filter) {

    $scope.currentrouteinPageCtrl = "";

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (scope, next, current)
        {
             console.log('Total ......route slug : ' + Object.keys(next.params).length);
             console.log(next.params.pageid);

             $scope.currentrouteinPageCtrl = next.params.pageid; 
             console.log($scope.currentrouteinPageCtrl);
        });

        $( window ).scroll(function() 
        {
            console.log($scope.currentrouteinPageCtrl); 

        });     


 });
```

when i change my route dynamically like /page/food and than /page/story
`$scope.currentrouteinPageCtrl` is taking both value food and story in window scroll event

i thought there is no need of that stil, i tried `$scope.apply()` that give me digest error so i tried this `$rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$apply();`

i also tried to get path from $location.path() but still facing same issue

thanks in advance